Spring boot + Angular CSRF protection, Cookie not set
I have an application setup consisting on a backend API and an Angular client. I configured csrf protection in backend like this:
  @Bean
    public CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        CookieCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository =  
        CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
        tokenRepository.setCookieName("XSRF-TOKEN");
        tokenRepository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return tokenRepository;
    }

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors().and()
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.withObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<CsrfFilter>() {

            @Override
            public <O extends CsrfFilter> O postProcess(O object) {
                object.setRequireCsrfProtectionMatcher(CsrfFilter.DEFAULT_CSRF_MATCHER);
                return object;
            }
        }).csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
        )
        .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .authorizeRequests(authz -> authz
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
         )
        .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    return http.build();
}

In Angular I just added the module  HttpClientXsrfModule which defaults with cookie and header that is configured in backend.
The response contains Set-Cookie header, but if I check document.cookie it doesn't contain XSRF-TOKEN.

I have even written a custom interceptor, that reads the cookie and putstoken in header, but as there is nothing in document.cookie, requests are not passing backend csrf protection.
Nr 2. Also, if I set a cookie in that tab document.cookie='test1=test1', it is not sent to backend. If I inspect HttpServletRequest#getCookies is is null.
My understanding is that cookies for that domain, are automatically sent with every request.
